# MATLAB cannot save changes to the path

Tags: matlab

When starting Matlab, I must now add new paths in order to get access to my functions. However, these paths cannot be saved, and I get the following message:
“MATLAB cannot save changes to the path.
The path file, pathdef.m, might be read-only or might be in a directory for which you do not have write access.
You can save pathdef.m to a different location. In order for MATLAB to use the pathdef.m in future sessions, you need to save it in your MATLAB startup directory (the directory from which you start MATLAB).
Do you want to save pathdef.m to another location?”

Before that, it works perfectly fine.

I tried the following solutions, but none of them did work:

- restart the computer
- restart Matlab
- start Matlab as Administrator
- re-install Matlab
- re-install Matlab directly in C:\ (not in C:\Programs)
- share Matlab-folders
- check the number of „pathdef.m“ (and there is only one)
- change UAC to the smallest level
- try another license

The problem seems to be between Windows and Matlab. I have Windows 8.1 Pro (64-bit), and I used Matlab 2015a.

Any help to solve the problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: The easy way is creating `startup.m` on the startup folder, and add the paths on that file. MATLAB automatically runs `startup.m` when initiated.

Comment: Alternatively, you can save `pathdef.m` to another location, as MATLAB tells you

Comment: Use [`savepath`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savepath.html) to generate a `pathdef.m` and place it in your startup directory.